# NodeJS Express Sequelize seeing Body Values as Null

Tags: node.js, json, express, sequelize.js

I'm at a genuine dead end here.

I have an API built in NodeJS Express with Sequelize. The Method causing trouble is this one:

```
create(req, res){
    agentGame.create({
        Agent: req.body.Agent,
        Game: req.body.Game,
    })
    .then(agentGame => res.status(201).send(agentGame))
    .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
},
```

Whenever I send any data to this it always, without fail says both Agent and Game are Null.

This is the request body: {"Agent":3,"Game":1}

This is the Model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('AgentsGames', {
    ID: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    Agent: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false
    },
    Game: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false
    },
    StarterSent: {
      type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
      allowNull: true
    },
    StarterPainted: {
      type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
      allowNull: true
    },
  }, {
    tableName: 'AgentsGames'
  });
};
```

I cannot find any reason for it to keep saying the body values are Null. I can manually enter the values into the Database, if I set the model to allow Null values it will create the entry with null values.

Any help?

Comment: Do you use `express.json()`? If you are sending data as JSON, are you providing headers with content type?

Comment: Hi.

Yes, all the other routes and methods are working, just this one has this weird, unexplained behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This has now been fixed.

Deleted Node_Modules, reinstalled with npm install and restarted the app and it started working again, so think a fault in Express.Json somewhere was to blame.